# Multiple entries in a single row in a single column postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm having trouble with a table in my database. If I'm building a blog for example, a post on my blog should have multiple tags. I thought about having a `tag_id` column in my posts table that corresponds to `tag_id` in my `tags` table but that would mean that each post can only have one tag. I want each post to be able to have multiple tags. How can I enter multiple ids in my `tag_id` column in a single row (corresponding to a specific post). If it does not work with ids, can it work with tag names? I realize that I can enter multiple tag names, but then how do I connect the tag names with the `tags_names` in the `tags` table?

Comment: You have all the answers here: [**Implementation for tag based mail system by JOINS using MySQL Database**](https://blog.praveen.science/implementation-for-tag-based-mail-system-by-joins-using-mysql-database/) - It's an article I wrote like few years ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to my article [**Implementation for tag based mail system by JOINS using MySQL Database**](https://blog.praveen.science/implementation-for-tag-based-mail-system-by-joins-using-mysql-database/), which I wrote a few years ago, I would say what you have done is right. So ultimately, your table should look like this:

**Posts**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `mailserver`.`mails`;  
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ID | Subject          | Content                                      |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Welcome Home     | Hey man, Welcome to your new house.          |
|  2 | Hi               | Hey there, wanna see what you doing at home! |
|  3 | Your promotion   | This is to say about your promotion!         |
|  4 | What the hell?   | College is really bad!                       |
|  5 | My Project Work! | I have hereby attached my project work!      |
+----+------------------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Tags:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `mailserver`.`maillabel`;  
+----+-----------+--------+
| ID | LabelName | MailID |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | inbox     |      1 |
|  2 | inbox     |      3 |
|  3 | inbox     |      5 |
|  4 | personal  |      1 |
|  5 | friends   |      2 |
|  6 | office    |      3 |
|  7 | personal  |      4 |
|  8 | college   |      5 |
+----+-----------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Relationship Table**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `mailserver`.`maillabel`;  
+----+-----------+--------+
| ID | LabelName | MailID |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | inbox     |      1 |
|  2 | inbox     |      3 |
|  3 | inbox     |      5 |
|  4 | personal  |      1 |
|  5 | friends   |      2 |
|  6 | office    |      3 |
|  7 | personal  |      4 |
|  8 | college   |      5 |
+----+-----------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Ultimately, you will be interested in two things.

1. How to get the posts from one particular tag?
2. How to get all the tags of one particular post?

To answer the above queries:

**All posts for a particular tag, `inbox`:**

```
mysql> SELECT *  
       FROM   `mailserver`.`mails`
              JOIN `mailserver`.`maillabel`
                ON `mailserver`.`mails`.`id` = `mailserver`.`maillabel`.`mailid`
       WHERE  `mailserver`.`maillabel`.`labelname` = 'inbox'; 
+----+------------------+-----------------------------------------+----+-----------+--------+
| ID | Subject          | Content                                 | ID | LabelName | MailID |
+----+------------------+-----------------------------------------+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Welcome Home     | Hey man, Welcome to your new house.     |  1 | inbox     |      1 |
|  3 | Your promotion   | This is to say about your promotion!    |  2 | inbox     |      3 |
|  5 | My Project Work! | I have hereby attached my project work! |  3 | inbox     |      5 |
+----+------------------+-----------------------------------------+----+-----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And to answer the second question...

**Getting the tags of one particular post:**

```
mysql> SELECT labelname  
       FROM   `mailserver`.`maillabel`
              JOIN `mailserver`.`mails`
                ON `mailserver`.`mails`.`id` = `mailserver`.`maillabel`.`mailid`
       WHERE  `mailserver`.`mails`.`id` = 3; 
+-----------+
| labelname |
+-----------+
| inbox     |
| office    |
+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This implementation holds good for **MySQL Server 5.x**. This concept can be applied to Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, and so on. Even we can apply this to MS Access. Just the syntax of the queries differ in each database.

Comment: adding  a non-unique```post_id ``` to my ```tags``` table should work out! Thank you so much!!!